# Eclipse Tycho is failing: Cannot satisfy dependency: To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm trying and failing to build an Eclipse RCP application with Tycho.

The application is kind of taken from Vogella's tutorial.

I run "mvn clean verify" and the error I'm getting is :-

```
    [INFO] --- tycho-p2-repository:2.7.5:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) @ com.jim.mp.build.product ---
    [WARNING] Parameter 'qualifier' (user property 'buildQualifier') is read-only, must not be used in configuration
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- tycho-p2-repository:2.7.5:archive-repository (default-archive-repository) @ com.jim.mp.build.product ---
    [WARNING] Parameter 'qualifier' (user property 'buildQualifier') is read-only, must not be used in configuration
    [INFO] Building zip: C:\My_Devs\Eclipse-Headless-Tycho-Vogella\com.jim.mp.build\releng\com.jim.mp.build.product\target\com.jim.mp.build.product-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- tycho-p2-director:2.7.5:materialize-products (materialize-products) @ com.jim.mp.build.product ---
    [INFO] Installing product com.vogella.tasks.product.product for environment win32/win32/x86_64 to C:\My_Devs\Eclipse-Headless-Tycho-Vogella\com.jim.mp.build\releng\com.jim.mp.build.product\target\products\com.vogella.tasks.product.product\win32\win32\x86_64
    Installing com.vogella.tasks.product.product 0.0.1.
    Installation failed.
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
            Software being installed: to-do 0.0.1 (com.vogella.tasks.product.product 0.0.1)
            Missing requirement: toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 0.0.1 requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 0.0.0' but it could not be found
            Cannot satisfy dependency:
                    From: to-do 0.0.1 (com.vogella.tasks.product.product 0.0.1)
                    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingcom.vogella.tasks.product.product.configuration [0.0.1,0.0.1]
            Cannot satisfy dependency:
                    From: toolingcom.vogella.tasks.product.product.configuration 0.0.1
                    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [0.0.1,0.0.1]
```

I've tried Tycho versions `2.7.5` and `3.0.4`
I've tried removing `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator` from my product file entirely
I've tried completely deleting my Maven .m2 repo and starting from scratch

Was hoping for an error free Tycho build of my simple application

I actually got the errors above

Comment: It isn't possible to debug this from just a log. What is `toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator`? What does "kind of taken" mean.

Comment: [Vogella's Tycho example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) works for me. One cannot say what you did wrong if you do not tell what you did differently.